# Moving a sprite in the update function Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I made a function which made an SKLabelNode every time the mouse is clicked...
now i want to refer to these nodes and change there position outside the function they were made in .. the update function how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable (or an array if you have more sprites)

```
var label: SKLabelNode?
```

In your create method you can assign the new sprite to the variable

```
func createLabel() {

  label = SKLabelNode()
  ...
}
```

Now you can manipulate the label in your update method

```
func update() {
  label.DoSomething...
  ....
}
```